# Why does this query unify with this clause in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, unification

I think I have a fundamental misunderstanding about unification. Here are my two clauses:

```
test(func(X), X, 1) :- X == X.
test(func(X), Y, 0) :- X \== Y.
```

So- If I query test(func(X), Y, D), I would expect it to only be provable with the second clause, and D will be 0. This is because (I think\I am trying to) ensure that X must be equal to X, in the first clause. So my query shouldn't unify because X is not the same as Y. I thought == tests that the two operands are the same variables. And X and Y clearly aren't.

But the output:

```
| ?- test(func(X), Y, D).

D = 1
Y = X ? ;

D = 0
```

So it is saying that it unifies with the first clause if Y = X. But, Y is not equal to X. What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: @lurker I think the cause of the confusion is that if you query `?- X == Y` you get false. And yet OP is querying with X and Y which *look* like they're getting passed right on to a strict equality test.

Comment: @aBathologist ah yes, you're right. I didn't catch the `=/2` versus `==/2` issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first answer, `D = 1, Y = X` accords with your first definition. I think you're expecting that when you query `?- test(func(X), Y, D).` it should fail for the first definition, because the `X` and `Y` are different variables, but the first definition should only succeed if the two variables are identical.

However, in the head of your clause, you have the same variable appearing twice: `test(func(X), X, 1) :- X == X.` (As @CapelliC pointed out, `X == X` is superfluous here.) When you query `?- func(func(X), Y, D).`, Prolog tries to unify this clause with the head of your first rule. It unifies `func(X)` with `func(X)` and `Y` with `X` and `1` with `1`. Once this pattern-matching unification has succeeded, it then tests the body of the rule to see if the criteria are met. Since `Y` has been unified with `X`, the two variables will match the strict equality condition---during the pattern matching, you've unified `Y` with the same variable as `X`.

Note the following two queries:

```
?- X == Y.
false.

?- Y = X, X == Y.
X = Y.
```

The second is similar to what's happening with the query that's confusing you.  If you rewrite your first rule in accordance with @CapelliC's suggestion,

```
test(func(X), Y, 1) :- X == Y.
```

Then it will function as expected, because, in this case, a free variable in the second argument will be unified with a different variable than that within the `func/1` term, and *then* the two variables won't satisfy strict equality (but if the two variables are unified with a ground term, they will pass).

Comment: Thanks very much. The unification example helped clear up why it behaved this way. I was (and still am, I think) confused on all the difference 'equality' operators, like =, ==, is, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`X == X` it's a sort of tautology (always true), and clearly your first clause could equivalently be

```
test(func(X), X, 1).
```

I think you should write it like the second one

```
test(func(X), Y, 1) :- X == Y.
```